# How to search Wikipedia API for pages by location type?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

The WikiPedia API shows a way of searching for pages using properties like coordinates and a radius: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:GeoData

Is it possible to make that query and to also filter the the returned results by supported location types: country, satellite, state, adm1st, adm2nd, adm3rd, city, isle, mountain, river, waterbody, event, forest, glacier, airport, railwaystation, edu, pass, camera, landmark?